# neural net model for finding feature relationship to output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I was trying to create a simple neural net model for finding the relationship for features to output. For example, I have feature sets {x1,x2... ,xn} => y. I am expecting from neural-net is to adjust the weight and relationship across features to form output y.

For my tests, I used a simple feature set as {x1, x2, y} => y. Here I expected my model should be able to easily find weight for x1 and x2 as 0 with minimal training and find 100% accuracy easily. In reality my feature relationship would be more complicated.

However, my model is failing to get any reasonable accuracy. I tried with about 1000 samples and 300 epoch.

I tried multiple simple models built with Keras including 4-Dense layers with 100 hidden layers and LSTM models.

Is my expectation reasonable here. What is the best model for achieving this? Any help is appreciated. Let me know if any more details required.

here is one simple model I was testing with:

```
        # Init Keras
        self.regressor = Sequential()

        self.regressor.add(Dense(units = 100, init='uniform', activation='relu', input_shape = X_shape))
#         self.regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.regressor.add(Dense(units = 100, activation='relu'))
#         self.regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.regressor.add(Dense(units = 100, activation='relu'))
#         self.regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.regressor.add(Dense(units = 100, activation='relu'))
        self.regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.regressor.add(Flatten())

        self.regressor.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid'))
#         self.regressor.add(Dense(units = 1, activation="tanh"))
#         self.regressor.add(Dense(units = 1, activation="softmax"))


        self.regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: You have a fixed number of features i.e 3, that means you not need LSTM layers. Dense layers will be good. Also, it would be helpful if you can post the code of model.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal 3 features is just for an example. in reality I have 600+ (60x14)features. for validation of my model, I modified my features including the actual output itself as here: {x1, x2, y} => y. Here, I was expecting, model should be able to learn and give 100% accuracy. Posing one model code above.